# Heroku cannot build Angular2 application

Tags: node.js, heroku, angular

I created angular2 application using angular-cli.
Next I want to build it and deploy to heroku, so I updated scripts section in `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "heroku-prebuild": "npm install angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.17",
  "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build --dev"
}
```

When i run `npm install` on local machine application builds without errors. The same is when I run it using bitbucket pipelines, but when I try deploy it to heroku build fails.

This is part of message:

```
  0ms additional asset processing
  1922ms chunk asset optimization
   94% asset optimizationError in bail mode: [default] /tmp/build_c10a47380f869e4f82169d259a47dab7/src/app/app.component.ts:5:12
  remote:        Cannot find name 'require'.
  remote:        
  remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-95-generic
  remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_c10a47380f869e4f82169d259a47dab7/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_c10a47380f869e4f82169d259a47dab7/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_c10a47380f869e4f82169d259a47dab7/.npmrc"
  remote:        npm ERR! node v6.1.0
  remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
  remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  remote:        npm ERR! xxxxxx@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build --dev`
  remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
  remote:        npm ERR!
  remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the xxxxxx@0.0.0 postinstall script 'ng build --dev'.
  remote:        npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
  remote:        npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the xxxxxx package,
  remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  remote:        npm ERR!     ng build --dev
  remote:        npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
  remote:        npm ERR!     npm bugs xxxxxx
  remote:        npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
  remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls xxxxxx
  remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
  remote:        
  remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_c10a47380f869e4f82169d259a47dab7/npm-debug.log
  remote: 
  remote: -----> Build failed
  remote:        
  remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
  remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
  remote:        
  remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
  remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
  remote:        
  remote:        Love,
  remote:        Heroku
  remote:        
  remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
  remote: 
  remote:  !     Push failed
  remote: Verifying deploy...
  remote: 
  remote: ! Push rejected to xxxxxx.
  remote:
```

Do you have any idea why heroku cannot build angular2 application?
How to fix this problem?